# Magento2 - Enterprise Edition technical differences compared to Community Edition

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

I am interested in technical differences between Magento2 EE and CE editions.
Questions I would like to find answers to are:

1. How can I test my custom CE extension on EE? Assuming that I don't have any access to EE whatsoever.
2. What are the differences(if any) in extension development for EE and CE?
3. Often extension providers charge slightly more fore EE extension - is it purely because of technical differences and effort it takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will need to legally get a copy of Magento EE. That is either by signing up for their partner program or by having a client on Magento 2 EE. They do restrict access for EE because it costs money.
2. It depends. Generally they will be the same. However if extending EE functionality, then it can get very different because CE won't have that built in functionality.
3. They charge based on the follow factors

   1. Enterprise costs extra
   2. They need to recoup their Partner Program expenses
   3. Enhanced development for EE specific that does not go into the CE version
   4. Additional testing
   5. Enterprise customers also have more resources at hand